# Output XML items in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

```
try{
    #connection string
        // $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=mycooldb',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=mycooldb','root','toshiba1',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $q = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT FW_ArtSrcLink FROM FW_ArtSrc WHERE OneSet=1 and leagID=20");
    #call stored proc
        $q->execute();
    #get the rows into an array
        $result = $q->fetchAll();
        $newsStory = array();
    foreach($result as $r){
        while($xmlUrl = $r['FW_ArtSrcLink']){
            // WHILE there is a link out of 11 matching the $dbconn above, load XML file and convert to channel->item
            $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
            $newsStory[] = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;
            # -> Setup XML
        } //while
    }
    # -----> Load News Stories
        for($i = 0;$i<sizeof($newsStory); $i++){
            //// judging by your code, these are the things you wanted to echo
            # Source of Article Info-->
            echo $newsStory[$i]->item->title;
            echo $newsStory[$i]->item->link;

            # Actual News Article Info -->
            echo $newsStory[$i]->item->title;
            echo 'desc: '.$newsStory[$i]->item->description;
        }   // for()
} // try
```

I need help with the above code. There are 11 results from the $`dbconn` query, but I need each result load and converted with `simplexml_load_file();` so that all of the 11 records, having 15-20 links can be loaded too. Totaling about *15*11= 165 links*

```
foreach($result as $r){
            while($xmlUrl = $r['FW_ArtSrcLink']){
                // WHILE there is a link out of 11 matching the $dbconn above, load XML file and convert to channel->item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you started a foreach loop that you don't need inside the for loop, remove that and change the assignments to the variable $story into echoes.

```
////// modify your example code as follows:

# -----> Load News Stories

    //// if you haven't already, this is the place to send the content-type text/xml header
    header( "Content-Type: application/xml" ); //// if you've already sent this, then comment out this line
    //// note, many browsers will not display raw xml if it has not been styled - you may have to "view source" to see the xml - this is normal
    //// if you omit this header, the browser will probably assume it got text/HTML instead.

    for($i = 0;$i<sizeof($newsStory); $i++){

    //// judging by your code, these are the things you wanted to echo
# Source of Article Info-->
        echo $newsStory[$i]->title;
        echo $newsStory[$i]->link;

# Actual News Article Info -->
        echo $newsStory[$i]->title;
        echo $newsStory[$i]->description;

        //// foreach ($newsStory[$i] as $story){ //// remove this loop, you do not need it - the for($i) loop is already iterating through your news stories. :)


    }   // for()
```

Comment: This brings me back to square one though. I need to get ALL the title, desc, link from EACH source. Currently there are 11 sources being pulled. Each source has ~15-20 items. so 15*11=165 links... i only have 11, please see updated code above. I'd appreciate it if you help further @Steve

Comment: when you echo $newsStory[$i]->title; does it say "Array()" or does it give a string title?

Comment: No, it echos all the titles, but only 11 of them

Comment: How do I get it to loop through all the titles for a given $r?